# Android studio gradle build failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Already a couple of hours cant get why gradle gives me the next error ,after i added to my project google maps `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

App gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("keystore.jks")
            storePassword "chisinau2015"
            keyAlias "ehospice"
            keyPassword "chisinau2015"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ehospice.android.ehospice"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'uk.co.deanwild:flowtextview:2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3.1'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Any one got any idea whats wrong , everything happened when i added last compile google maps

Comment: You pass 65K methods read this https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: multidex i use just in gradle ?

Comment: thank you @Saeed picked just maps from services